# How to prevent the duplication of any value in a column within a CSV file (python)

Tags: python, csv

**I am wondering how to make my code function so it does not allow any of the same values to be entered into a column in my CSV file created through python.** So I need to read into the CSV file and check if any names have already been entered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show what have you tried?

Comment: I'm unsure what to try @pavan